# AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

I am trying to loops through table layout to check the button for a condition and then to change them with `setText`.
The problem I am having is before that I am getting a `ClassCastException`.
I see that it says I can't cast a Button to a ViewGroup, but I'm not sure why that it is happening, I am not trying to change anything at that point.
I believe this line (69), is the problem, but nty sure why.

`View view = ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildAt(i));`

Code:

```
public Button aiPlayerPick() {
        Button btn = null;
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tableLayout.getChildCount(); rowIndex++) {
            View tableLayoutChild = tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex);
            if (tableLayoutChild instanceof TableRow) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View view = ((ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildAt(i));
                    if (view instanceof Button && view.getTag() == aiPickedButton) {

                        View btn_v = view.findViewWithTag(aiPickedButton);
                        System.out.println("Button: " + btn_v);
                        //btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_v);

                        break;
                    } else {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return btn;
    }
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
     at com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity.aiPlayerPick(MainActivity.java:69)
     at com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity.playerClick(MainActivity.java:49)
     at com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity.humanPlayerTurn(MainActivity.java:34)
     at com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity.receiveClick(MainActivity.java:29)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're storing a variable of type `View`, using the cast `(ViewGroup)` forces a cast to happen before being stored. You're taking the child of the `TableRow` and casting it to `ViewGroup`, but its parent is actually `View` so it fails.

You don't need the second cast, since `getChildAt()` returns `View`:

```
View view = ((ViewGroup) tableLayoutChild).getChildAt(i);
```

Comment: Perfect. Cheers mate